# Visualizing custom gates in Cirq

Tags: quantum-gate, programming, cirq

I'm trying to visualize a custom gate in Cirq. I have through [this](https://cirq.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gates.html) page, which briefly mentions how to create custom gates in Cirq. However, I'm getting errors when trying to visualize it.

My current code defines a class `CustomGate`, which inherits from `cirq.Gate` class.

```
import numpy as np
import cirq 
class CustomGate(cirq.Gate):
    def __init__(self, unitary):
        self.unitary = unitary
        self.numQubits = int(np.log2(unitary.shape[0]))

    def _num_qubits_(self):
        return self.numQubits

    def _unitary_(self):
        return self.unitary

    def _circuit_diagram_info_(self, args='cirq.CircuitDiagramInfoArgs') -> 'cirq.CircuitDiagramInfo':
        return cirq.CircuitDiagramInfo(wire_symbols=("CG",), exponent=1.0, connected=True)
```

The usage is as follows:

```
# Define custom gate
customUnitary = np.eye(4)    # The custom unitary matrix would go here
CG = CustomGate(customUnitary)

# Setup circuit
q = cirq.LineQubit.range(2)
circuit=cirq.Circuit()
circuit.append(CG(q[0], q[1]))

# Visualize circuit
print(circuit)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 42, in <module>
    print(circuit)
  File "/Users/pgu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cirq/circuits/circuit.py", line 338, in __str__
    return self.to_text_diagram()
  File "/Users/pgu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cirq/circuits/circuit.py", line 1609, in to_text_diagram
    transpose=transpose)
  File "/Users/pgu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cirq/circuits/circuit.py", line 1668, in to_text_diagram_drawer
    get_circuit_diagram_info, include_tags)
  File "/Users/pgu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cirq/circuits/circuit.py", line 1924, in _draw_moment_in_diagram
    info = get_circuit_diagram_info(op, args)
  File "/Users/pgu/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cirq/circuits/circuit.py", line 1818, in _get_operation_circuit_diagram_info_with_fallback
    info))
ValueError: Wanted diagram info from <__main__.CustomGate object at 0x10379bb90>.on(cirq.LineQubit(0), cirq.LineQubit(1)) for 2 qubits but got cirq.CircuitDiagramInfo(wire_symbols=('CG',), exponent=1.0, connected=True, exponent_qubit_index=None, auto_exponent_parens=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making a two qubit gate but the circuit diagram info only has one wire label. Change `wire_symbols=("CG",)` to `wire_symbols=("CG", "#2")`.

Note that, since you're using default values for the diagram info you can just return the tuple `return "CG", "#2"` instead of bothering to wrap it in the more complicated data type.

Note that cirq does include `cirq.MatrixGate`, which takes an arbitrary unitary similar to what your custom gate is doing.